# SQL SELECT using three tables alias error

Tags: mysql, sql, select

My companies table contains detail data such as company name.

My sites table maps to the companies table in the company_sites table because companies can have multiple sites.

For example, Jim Co (id: 1000) has jim.com (id: 2000).

These are mapped as company_sites:id = 1; company_id: 1000; site_id: 2000.

How can I select all fields for Jim Co from companies where site_id = 2000?

I'm getting an alias error for companies when I try this.

Here's what I have so far:

```
SELECT * 
FROM companies 
INNER JOIN companies ON companies.id = company_sites.company_id
WHERE company_sites.site_id = 2000
```

Comment: The semicolon in line#3 should be a comma.

Comment: How is the alias defined ?

Comment: Hi Jim, you could really help us out by submitting the query you have so far. Also, the specifics of the alias error you mention could be helpful too.

Comment: of course, sorry. i posted it above. thanks

Comment: `FROM companies INNER JOIN companies` ?  Think you probably meant for one of those two tables to be `company_sites` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you intended to join to the `company_sites` table.

Try this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM companies 
INNER JOIN companies_sites ON companies.id = company_sites.company_id
WHERE company_sites.site_id = 2000
```

Comment: This works Kara. I don't know why I couldn't see that. Having a hard day I guess. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM companies c, company_sites s WHERE c.id = s.company_id && c.id = 2000;
```

Comment: This query returns the incorrect company.

Comment: Question was for a query by Site ID, not by Company ID; nor is "&&" the correct ANSI SQL operator for `AND`.

Comment: Probably didn't see the scroll bar at the bottom, and In MySQL `&&` is fine.